# How can I solve the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let we have the following sequence 
$$y_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\  \sqrt{n^2+n}}$$ find the limit of the sequence $y_n$ decide whether it is increasing or decreasing

Comment: Username: "Arab belly punching"?

Comment: @parsiad Something that gives us the laughs but none of our business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 
Prove that $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq \sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\leq\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}}$$
$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq y_n\leq\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}}$$
Then use squeeze lemma
It is a increasing sequence
Knowing that $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq y_n\leq\frac{1}{n}$$
We have that $y_n\leq\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+n+1}}\leq y_{n+1}$
And easy you can show that $$\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+n+1}}$$ 
So $$y_
n\leq y_{n+1}$$

Comment: Can you explain it more ?

Comment: Increasing or decreasing sequence ?

Comment: @Arabbellypunching The sum is larger than $n$ times the smallest number the sum reaches.  Likewise, the sum is smaller than than $n$ times the largest number the sum reaches.

Comment: How can I prove it is increasing or decreasing sequence ?

Comment: @SimpleArt how can I prove whether this sequence is increasing or decreasing ?

Comment: @Arabbellypunching I edit the answer.

Comment: This is strange: this answer was upvoted, never downvoted, accepted even, but the argument about the monotonicity is completely wrong.

Comment: The claim following "Knowing this" contains a mistake, since $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}}$ simplifies to $1$, not $\frac{1}{n}$.