# Monotonity and sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Let us consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that 
$$a_n=\frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+1}}+ \frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+2}} + \dots +\frac {1}{\sqrt {n^2+n}}.$$ Show that the sequence is monotone.

This question is already posted, but the answers are wrong.

Comment: Do you mean [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088985/how-can-i-solve-the-following-sequence)?

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake in a fraction.

Comment: It looks like each $a_n$ is clearly greater than $a_{n-1}$ since it gets a positive term added. Am I missing something?

Comment: You also substract some of the first terms.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata's_inequality gives a way to go.

Comment: How can I use it? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: Another, probably simpler way, is to exploit the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality][1], given that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. In particular
$$-2+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\int_{0}^{1/n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}}\geq \frac{1}{n^2}\left[\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\right]$$
and a similar inequality in the opposite direction holds. Once we prove $l_n\leq a_n\leq r_n$ and $r_n\leq l_{n+1}$ we are done.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: While the Accepted Answer on the duplicate Question does contain errors, this scarcely justifies posting a known duplicate.  You have the reputation needed to Comment on the posts of others, so you should use that privilege rather than repeating the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I solve the following sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088985/how-can-i-solve-the-following-sequence)